# glassfish server.policy (JAAS) URLPermission Failed Permission Check POST

Tags: rest, permissions, glassfish-4, jaas, policy

I have a library that communicates to various devices.  These devices post information back to the library on port 8080.   In Glassfish 4.1  I get a large number of these log messages.  Interesting I'm getting data from the library.

```
[2018-07-24T11:34:25.828-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] []
[javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=171
_ThreadName=DCThread_120.57.115.18_255_-1_15] [timeMillis: 1532450065828]
[levelValue: 800] [[ JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission
Check,context(null)Permission(("java.net.URLPermission""http://120.57.115.18:8080/" "POST:AuthorizationConnectionSOAPActionUser-Agent"))]]
```

I've tried to configure the server.policy for the respective domain to allow these posts.  I have not been successful.

```
grant {
    permission java.net.URLPermission "http:*", "POST";
};
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regards,
Dave

Comment: Is your library deployed with the application archive, or on the application server's class path? Is your GlassFish running under a security manager? (I presume not, since your library calls would be failing otherwise).

Comment: Something else of potential relevance: The assigned `URLPermission` does not actually [imply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLPermission.html#implies-java.security.Permission-) the checked one; the former's actions string should become `"POST:*"` for that to become the case.